# SPHERO with reality augmented

Tags: sphero-api, sphero

I tried to use sphero with vuforia.
But after the connection bluetooth, appears black screen. The sphero is OK, just vuforia does not work
Someone tried use the two sdk together?

Answer (score 0):

Using Sphero with the vuforia has never been tested and is not officially supported.  Sphero has a proprietary augmented reality plugin.